# limit on 1 gbps included bandwidth on an ovh dedicated server?

Tags: cloud, bandwidth, ovh, dedicated-server

i know this might not be the best place for posting this but this is by far the biggest and diverse community from coders to technical experts so i am taking my chances in hope that someone comes across this and point me in some direction. I plan to use OVH dedicated servers specifically speaking the infra-1 server for a project of mine that will be heavy on webcam video streams sharing and i see it has 1 gbps included bandwidth that is un-metered but i have my doubts especially after reading FAQ and poking around the forums. So what i want to ask is how much of this included 1 gbps can i really utilize before being throttled or capped as i have found out in forums that its actually half i.e. 500 mbps. Also if i plan to purchase dedicated  1gbps bandwidth will that be exclusively assigned to me without any throttling and available 24/7 right. and lastly un-metered means there is no upper limit on traffic. Need help from those who have some similar experience working with providers offering dedciated servers and bandwidth.